# Boxplot after applying model then to show the slope values

Tags: boxplot

I want to show the slope values after showing the distribution of each group.

with the simple useage of 2 vaiables it is not showing the box only showing the distribution of dots.i want to show the distribution of dots then showing the slope values of regression